# what affine operation i should use to make image output look like one on right hand side?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i want to make output of left hand image like right hand by performing affine operations like, scaling , translation ,shear and rotation.[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yes you should use scaling, rotation etc... are you asking for the quantities? Or for a process that can uncover those quantities? Look up affine image registration.

Comment: jst want to know how much rotation scaling will  make left image look like right one thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to perform image registration in matlab then have a look at [this great toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20057-b-spline-grid-image-and-point-based-registration) off the file exchange. Image registration is the process of uncovering the transformation parameters than will align a source image to a reference image as closely as possible. If you use affine registration, the result will be an affine transformation matrix that will transform your left image to your right image. One thing to watch out for is that by default the registration may take the upper left corner of the image for the centre of rotation but you will more likely want the centre of the image to be the centre of rotation in which case simply translate the image by half its dimensions before and after applying a transformation / registration.

However if you literally just want to know the angle of rotation for this one single image, then use a protractor.